# How much time does the browser need to close a child window?

Tags: javascript, performance, settimeout

I have an interactive program where the user calls one after the other a series of translations of a definite source word into languages that are handled in Google Translate.
The user need not close the child windows himself. That does the program as soon as the user notes his conclusion depending on the kind of translation Google Translate produces.
I have already tried for weeks to solve the problem that the program reports that a certian window can not be closed after the program should have executed page.close().
I am now near to the solution, I think, that the browser needs some time for closing and only after that can detect that the window is closed.
Essentially the code which still does not conform to my wishes reads

```
function loadpage() {
    page=window.open("url-code for calling specific translation by GT", "GT", "scrollbars=1, resizable=1, height=400, top=200, left=300, width=400", true);
}

function crucial() {
    page.close();
    setTimeOut(function() {
        if (page.closed) {
            alert("succesful closing");
        } else {    
            alert("The window can't be closed!");
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Alas ! Neither of the two alerts show up. In some cases, depending on the delay time ?, the window closes. 
The advice I got from Bergi to check inside the delayed function by if (!page.closed) did not work.
What works seems to have to fulfill the following conditions:
 1. Declare the setTimeOut function. 
 2. create function preferential in the format function() {alertcheck()}
    (the delay time seems not to matter; it works even with 0 anyhow.)

```
    var timeoutID;
function preferential() {
timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(){alertcheck()}, 0);
}
function alertcheck()  {
if (page.closed) {
    alert("succesful closing");
} else {    
    alert("The window could not be closed!");
}
}
```

Why it is like that interests me a lot. At least I hope, that readers can repeat this experiment with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> the program reports that a certian window can not be closed after the program should have executed page.close()

Closed windows cannot be closed. You should always use

```
if (!page.closed)
    page.close();
```

Comment: What you say there is evident and it is true, that when I wotk with the condition  if (!page.closed)  I get the desired result, while not with the condition if (page.closed).
Then, can you tell me what the logical difference is between

    function crucial1()  {
 page.close();
 if (page.closed) {
  alert("succesful closing");
 } else { 
  alert("La fenestro ne povis esti fermita!");
 }
    }

and

function crucial2()  {
 page.close();
 if (!page.closed)  {
  alert("La fenestro ne povis esti fermita!");
 } else {
  alert("succesful closing");
 } 
    }

Comment: I don't see any, however my answer suggest to put the `page.close()` statement itself inside if-condition.